# How to solve the phenomenon that checkbox disappears by applying in materialize

Tags: css

this is a student who's making my own personal homepage.
I'm really sorry I'm using a translator because I'm not good at English.;D

by the way...I want to put the button effect of the 'materializecss site', so I put the css code in the html and the checkbox disappears.

Checkbox is a secret comment, so it's important. I can't take it out.
But I can't give up the effect of the button.;D.... Can you tell me how to solve it?

<< materializecss >>

https://materializecss.com/

<< my code >>

https://jsfiddle.net/rvnqkdz8/

```html
<p class="secretWrap">
  <input type="checkbox" name="secret" class="checkbox" />
  <label for="secret"> SECRET </label>
</p>
<p class="clear"></p>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN0F8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTSMT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfp3N.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Hs0.png)

<<▲problem cartton images>>

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please can you edit your question. Please include code in the question.

Comment: Include code, not more images. We hate images.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use your Input checkbox as checked already as Following.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="secret" class="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

After that, If you want you can change it using your database

Answer (score 1):

*It's not an issue with materialize, but an issue with your code.
In your css, label isn't display.
Here is a workaround:*

**CSS:**

```
label[for="secret"] {display:block;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p class="secretWrap">
  <label for="secret">
                <input type="checkbox" name="secret" class="checkbox" />
      <span>SECRET</span> </label>
</p>
```

**Fille Link :** https://jsfiddle.net/8x0u45pn/

Answer (score 0):

Try change white (#fff) for black (#000) in your css file to replace the white in checkboxes.scss.

```
// CHECKBOXES CHECKED
[type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked + span:not(.lever):before {
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
[type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked + span:not(.lever):after {
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```